# get hidden details (eg. author) of a file as in windows

Tags: files

Is there a way to find, in Linux, details as given in Windows machine? By details, I mean author, etc. Like in this [figure](https://superuser.com/questions/494878/does-windows-8-have-a-status-bar-to-display-details-of-a-file) (Source : Super User).

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu GNOME details can be view in the properties of files or in the "Files" software, with the list view. You can personalize the list view for adding more details in preferences.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How I can find the "Préférences" window? I tried properties (I have English version), but I can't find the preferences window?

Comment: You should be able to find it:
In Ubuntu 18.04: By clicking on the application menu at the top bar "Files".
In Ubuntu 19.04: By clicking on the icon with 3 lines at the top right of the application.